# Are there report features for wso2 api manager

Tags: wso2

We have wso2 api manager v1.10 and an early version of das. We have 9 environments to manage and our deployment team and testers are wanting reports to show who is subscribed to our APIs and what versions of the APIs are mapped to backend services.

I have checked the wso2 doco and various sites to see if das could produce these types of reports but with no luck.

Does anyone know of any reporting feature or facility that could provide dependency and version reports?

Comment: What kind of reports are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no out of the box feature for report generation in APIM or DAS. But you can use [DAS REST API](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Analytics+REST+API+Guide) or database tables [`STATS_DB` and `APIM_DB`] to retrieve data and use some 3rd party report gen tools such as [jsreport](https://jsreport.net/) to generate reports.